# Meaning of EnvironmentEmulation

Tags: api, model, environment-emulation

Can anyone tell me the exact meaning of EnvironmentEmulation?

One usecase can be found in `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email`

```
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

if ($this->_type == 'price') {
    $this->_getPriceBlock()
        ->setStore($store)
        ->reset();
    foreach ($this->_priceProducts as $product) {
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->_customer->getGroupId());
        $this->_getPriceBlock()->addProduct($product);
    }
    $block = $this->_getPriceBlock()->toHtml();
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_PRICE_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
} else {
    $this->_getStockBlock()
        ->setStore($store)
        ->reset();
    foreach ($this->_stockProducts as $product) {
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->_customer->getGroupId());
        $this->_getStockBlock()->addProduct($product);
    }
    $block = $this->_getStockBlock()->toHtml();
    $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_STOCK_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
}

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

My understanding is that everything between`startEnvironmentEmulation` and `stopEnvironmentEmulation` is treated as under the `storeId` that was given as an argument.

But when I look at the example, the `templateId` takes the `storeId` directly as an argument. So there would be no need for en emulation here.
Am I right?

So far my only guess is, that there is a function deeper down in one of the methods that get the current store with something like `getCurrentStore`?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @MagePsycho you should post this as an answer, as it is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a task is executed in an emulated environment it will take the related store scope translation, configuration settings etc. 
REFER: 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/

Comment: I often look at Inchoo, but this posting slipped through. Thanks! :)